# localize VSTO addin according to the language of the office product

Tags: .net, localization, vsto

I'm developing a VSTO addin and want it to be localized according to the language version of the office product. In theory, that's how to do it:

```
int lcid = Application.LanguageSettings.get_LanguageID(Office.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI);
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(lcid);
```

For this to work I need `Application` to be initialized, of course. So the earliest point where I can execute this code is in the Startup event handler. At this point, however, `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()` already has been called, so at least the title of my custom ribbon tab is going to be displayed in the Windows language, which might be different. 
In the ribbon class I have a handler for the onLoad event, where I store an instance of `IRibbonUI` for later use. I could hand over this instance to the addin class and let it call `IRibbonUI.Invalidate()` on it. But this seems to be a bit strange - creating a ribbon just to invalidate it a couple of microseconds later. So I wonder - and ask here - whether there is a more elegant way to localize the ribbon of a vsto addin according to the language version of the office product.

(I've seen [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8013658/localize-office-add-in-based-on-office-language-pack-in-use-rather-than-windows), but the approach offered there [by this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8057989/1004651) looks even worse to me.)

Comment: re: worse approach: You mean, of course the registry lookup, right? The answer suggesting use of CurrentUICulture makes sense to me.

Comment: @Ishmaeel Sure. That other answer is newer than my question. I've just edited that part to make it clear. My first attempt (see the question) and both that new answer and the accepted answer here set CurrentUICulture. They differ in where to take it from.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can always override the [`CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addinbase.createribbonextensibilityobject.aspx) method or possibly override some of the other [`AddInBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee247700.aspx) methods (*BeginInit, Initialize, etc.*) to hook into the proper location in the AddIn load lifecycle.

I have overridden the `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` before to ensure that initialization code is run before the Ribbon is loaded. I have noticed that `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` and `Startup` events are triggered at random times. Sometimes `Startup` happens first - sometimes `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` fires first. I had to manually synchronize the two events to ensure any initialization code is executed prior to Ribbon creation. If `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject` fires first - the Application object has not yet been created.

#### Try this approach in `CreateRibbonExtensibility`:

```
 Outlook.Application app = this.GetHostItem<Outlook.Application>(typeof(Outlook.Application), "Application");
 int lcid = app.LanguageSettings.get_LanguageID(Office.MsoAppLanguageID.msoLanguageIDUI);
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(lcid);
```

This will retrieve a reference to the `Application` instance for you - regardless if it has been loaded in the `Initialize` yet.

Comment: CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject is called from ThisAddIn.Initialize (and a couple of methods in between in the call stack) - it is triggered by base.Initialize() just before the line where Application is set. I don't see how thread sync would help here. I am in the same thread that executes ThisAddIn.Initialize. To reach the line (in the generated code, which I do not want to touch) where Application is set I need to return from CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject.

Comment: Are you using the Ribbon Designer or Ribbon XML for the Fluent UI?

Comment: Thank you - works for me as well. Do you happen to know any documentation on GetHostItem<T>() that is more verbose than the MSDN pages? Otherwise I would just be so optimistic to assume that it is as light-weight as its "Get"-prefix is promising...